# Conditional Probability problem on Dice

Tags: probability, dice

A fair dice is rolled four times. What is the probability of obtaining two or more 6's given that no two successive outcomes were the same?

This is quite a straightforward problem, that I thought of myself, and want corroboration on my answer to it.

Is my thinking right, if I say that considering the four outcomes numbered $1, 2, 3, 4$, there are exactly three ways to get two $6$'s: $(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 4)$ and the probability of getting $6$ any of these outcomes, i.e. involving two $6$'s at these numbered outcomes and not a $6$ at the others, is $\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} = \frac{25}{1296}$. Hence, the total probability is $ \frac{3 \cdot 25}{1296} = \frac{25}{432}$

Please provide some inputs if I am correctly aligned.

Comment: I would have thought that if there are no two successive outcomes the same,, then the number of equally likely possibilities were $6\times 5\times 5\times 5 =750$ rather than $6^4=1296$.  This will also change the numerators and I think what you call $(1,4)$ could be less common than the other two

Comment: Thanks Henry, I think I got the flaw and your point makes sense. So if I go by this, my n(S) = 750 and my n(E) = 5*5 + 5*4 + 5*5 = 70 for the three respective outcomes I stated. So should we finish that at 7/75

Answer (score 1):

It says *given* no two successive outcomes are same. So $6^4$ is not the correct sample space. It should be $6 \cdot 5^3$.

Also for the favorable outcomes, when you have positions of two sixes with a single gap, that is positions - `1 and 3` or `2 and 4`, there are $2 \cdot 5\cdot 5$ favorable outcomes. But when the positions of sixes are `1 and 4`, there are only $5 \cdot 4$ favorable outcomes.

So the answer should be $ \ \displaystyle \frac {2\cdot5\cdot5 + 5\cdot4}{750} = \frac{7}{75}$

Comment: Thanks for establishing that clearly!!

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If no two successive rolls are the same, then you can only get at most $2$ sixes in $4$ rolls:

- first and third rolls with probability $\frac16 \times \frac55  \times \frac15 \times \frac55$
- first and fourth rolls with probability $\frac16 \times \frac55 \times \frac45 \times \frac15$
- second and fourth rolls with probability $\frac56 \times \frac15 \times \frac55 \times \frac15$

Add these up to get $\frac7 {75}$

Comment: I thought I knew this stuff, but I learnt a lot today. Thanks!!